# Something better than just an index for `tenant_id` column

Tags: mysql

I store totally separate data in the same table and I use the column `tenant_id` to separate it from each other. Since all queries include `WHERE tenant_id = ?` I have an index just on that column. I was wondering if there is a better/faster way than just an index, could I use MySQL partitioning here maybe? Or should I stick with an index?

Comment: How large is your table?

Comment: Right now there are ~200 tenants, but it could go in the ten thousands. The data don't need to be cross referenced across tenants, each tenant is a completely different data set. They each have their own products, orders etc.